# How to combine output of netsh wlan show networks | findstr /L /I "SSID authentication"?

Tags: batch-file, netsh

Batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims=: " %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks^|find /i "SSID"') do ( echo %%i.%%j )  
for /f "tokens=2*delims=: " %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks^|find /i "authentication"') DO (echo %%i )
```

I need output like this:

```
1. SSIDname1 : WPA2-personal
2. SSIDname2 : Open
3. ....
```

I have tried this way but failed:

```
for /f "tokens=2*delims=: " %%a in ('netsh wlan show networks^|find /i "authentication"') do (
    for /f "tokens=2*delims=: " %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks^|find /i "SSID"') do (
        echo %%i.%%j = %%a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete batch file solution, to meet the requirements at the time of posting.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "#=0"
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%G In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" WLAN Show Networks 2^> NUL ^|^
     "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "^SSID\> \<Authentication\>"^"'
) Do Set "i=%%G" & For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("%%H") Do (Set /A # %%= 2
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "i=!i:~,-1!. " & If !#! Equ 0 (If "%%I"=="" (
            Set /P "_=!i:* =!*Cloaked*: "<NUL) Else Set /P "_=!i:* =!%%I: "<NUL
        ) Else Echo !_!%%I
    EndLocal & Set /A # += 1)
Pause
```

*As you've made no attempt at the task yourself, there will be no explanation of the provided code, and no modifications will be made to it, should you decide to modify your question, or requirements, after its submission.*